Copying a range of values from row 1 to 250 in increment of 250 till the end
I am new to writing VBA codes.  I'm trying to copy a range of values from range B1 to 250 and paste into another sheet and repeat from range B251 in increment of 250, until the last row.
But cant seems to find any solution by using for loop
Sub forloop()

    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngLoopCtr As Range
    lngLastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    For lngLoopCtr = 1 To lngLastRow Step 250
        lngLoopCtr.Value.copy
        With Sheets("sheet1").Range("A")
        .PasteSpecial
        End With
    Next lngLoopCtr
    
End Sub


Firstly, why do you try this way, since you copy the range in the same sheet? I mean, why not copying all he range at once? Do you only want testing how such an iteration will work?

Yes..I'm trying to automate with SAP application

What do you mean by 'automation with SAP application'? Don't you copy from a workbook downloaded from SAP in another one, in another sheet? Or viceversa, which is the same... Why copying the same column, in slices,  in the same column of another worksheet and not copying the whole column content, at once?

You did not answer my clarification (from the above comment)...
So, if you only try testing such a solution, please try the next adapted code. It is faster, it avoids using the clipboard, it uses an array and drop its content at once. As didactic aspect, the code places a marker in column "B:B", where first row of the pasted slice is:
Sub forloopCopySlices()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, arrCopy, lastR1 As Long, rangEnd As Long
    Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngLoopCtr As Long, i As Long
    Const lngRows As Long = 250
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'sheet to be processed
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'sheet where to copy
    
    lngLastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in the processed sheet
    lastR1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.rows.count).End(xlUp).row   'last row of the sheet to copy
    
    For lngLoopCtr = 1 To lngLastRow Step lngRows
        rangEnd = IIf(lngLoopCtr + lngRows - 1 > lngLastRow, lngLoopCtr, lngLoopCtr + lngRows - 1) 'last slice row
        arrCopy = ws.Range("B" & lngLoopCtr & ":B" & rangEnd).Value 'place the range in an array to avoid clipboard using and being faster
        If lastR1 = 1 Then lastR1 = 1 Else: lastR1 = lastR1 + 1     'correct row where to paste
        If IsArray(arrCopy) Then
            ws1.cells(lastR1, "A").Resize(UBound(arrCopy), 1).Value = arrCopy
        Else
            ws1.cells(lastR1, "A").Value = arrCopy 'for the case when last slice contains ONLY A CELL
        End If
        i = i + 1 'increment the slice
        ws1.cells(lastR1, "B").Value = "Slice " & i 'a marker for eache copied slice start
        lastR1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.rows.count).End(xlUp).row      'recalculate the last row (where to copy the next slice)
    Next lngLoopCtr
    
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub



Copy requires to define ranges as Range object.
Loop counter is a number.
To copy only values this should be selected with the PasteSpecial method.

Apply something like this:
Sub forloop()

    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngLoopCtr As Long
    lngLastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    For lngLoopCtr = 1 To lngLastRow Step 250
        Range("B" & lngLoopCtr & ":B" & lngLoopCtr+249).Copy
        With Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & lngLoopCtr)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
    Next lngLoopCtr
    
End Sub


Hi it works, however when I change the range to use a table, it hit an runtime error '1004'
Sub forloop()
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngLoopCtr As Long
lngLastRow = Range("Table1[NSN]" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
For lngLoopCtr = 2 To lngLastRow Step 10
    Range("Table1[NSN]" & lngLoopCtr & ":Table1[NSN]" & lngLoopCtr + 9).copy
    With Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & lngLoopCtr)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
Next lngLoopCtr

End Sub

This is another issue. It is better if you want to use Table references try to create the code and when stuck post a new question. There are other problems in your sample code. Table references are not strings, rather Name objects which coerced to range. It's not accepted in this form by the Range method.
